# jQuery .on function not working with 2 functions on the same div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/182/

```html
<div class="short">
    <div class="panel">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        <span id="chk" class="name">Check</span>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.short').on('click', '.btn', function (e) {    
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});

$('.short').on('click', '.panel', function (e) {
    alert('check');
});
```

This whole div is dynamically created when a drag and drop happens

The problems I am having are :

- In positioning the (-) button to the top-right corner of the rectangle.
- When i click on (-) button the second function also gets triggered. How can i avoid this?

Comment: For your i) i'll say you could modify the css file and add `.btn { float: right; }` and eventually modify the size of the container or of the button. The rest has been answered.

Comment: thanks,it indeed helped.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the `event bubbling` to be happened,

```
$('.short').on('click', '.btn', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/183/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `button` is inside the `.panel`, it's normal that both events are being triggered at once. All you need to do is change the position of the `button`. Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d5FD/) that solves both problems with a single HTML change.

If you're not allowed to change the HTML, you can use stopPropagation() to prevent bubbling and use "float: right" on your `.btn` to make it appear on the right. You'll also need to increase the width of `.panel` to make the button appear on the right side properly. Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52c5R/) for this second solution.

Answer (score 1):

To position your button you can add the following styles

```
.panel{
    position:relative;
}
.btn.btn-default.btn-xs{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px; /*you can now position your button anywhere you want in the panel*/
    top:0px;
}
```

You don't need to resize the panel and the button will always be in the top right hand corner but it might overlap other elements if the container is small.

Like everyone else said event.stopPropogation() is probably best. It stops the event from being fired on parent elements.

```
$('.short').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/182/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.short').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {

               $(this).parent('div').remove();

             });

 $('.short').on('click', '.panel', function(e) {
                if(e.target.tagName=="DIV")
                {
                    alert('Check');
                }


             });
```

I have solved your problem in JSFiddle

Please Ref : [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2ZF/)